# Checking if tweet is in reply to deleted tweet

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm writing a program to scrape tweets between two specific dates from a user, while making sure that they are not retweets or replies. I am using **snscrape** and **tweepy**.

```
for i, tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('from:' + lines[x] + ' since:' + startDate + ' until:' + endDate).get_items()):
    if tweet.retweetedTweet is None and tweet.inReplyToTweetId is None and tweet.inReplyToUser is None:
```

This is what I have for the check, however, if the tweet is in reply to a tweet that has been deleted, then the tweet is no longer considered a reply and the check passes as `None`. Is there a way around this? I'm looking at pulling tweets from large companies like Tesco and Sainsburys and manually sorting through their tweets by hand will be tedious and want to find a way to fix this within the code.

An example of this is [this tweet](https://twitter.com/Tesco/status/1457793089330814984), as the code passes the check for `inReplyToTweetId is None`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this a lot quicker than I thought I would. Turns out, in the tweet object, the `mentionedUsers` array is empty for these specific tweets, so I added the following if statement which solved the problem:

```
if not ('@' in tweet.content and not tweet.mentionedUsers):
```

This just checks whether the user has a mention (@ symbol) in the actual text of the tweet and also whether the `mentionedUsers` array is empty to discard it as being a reply.